# How to convert numpy array of long string to list with only one element

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I read a file that has multiple lines to indicate filenames with `np.loadtxt`

for example, the txt file content is:

> 000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg
>   000925_0017_01_0006_P00_01.tifresize.jpg
>   000919_0017_01_0012_P00_01.tifresize.jpg

This txt file has file name `split_file_name`.
I use for loops to decode each file name and do some processing for each image as:

`for file_name in list(np.loadtxt(split_file_name, dtype=bytes)):
    file_name.decode("utf-8")
    # other processing...`

The output for `list(np.loadtxt(split_file_name, dtype=bytes))` is:

> [b'000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg',
>   b'000925_0017_01_0006_P00_01.tifresize.jpg',
>   b'000919_0017_01_0012_P00_01.tifresize.jpg']

however, when there is only one line in the file split_file_name, as:

> 000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg

after using `np.loadtxt()` the output is:

> array(b'000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg', 
>         dtype='|S40')

when use `list(np.loadtxt(split_file_name, dtype=bytes))` in this case,
it fails with

> TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array.

The reason is that after `np.loadtxt` it returns an numpy array object which has only one long string, but list() cannot convert it directly to a list contain only one `b'000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg'`

How should I do to ensure that it works for only one line txt file?

Comment: Please accept the answer, if the question is answered ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
In [1]: [np.array(b'000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg', dtype='|S40').tolist()]
Out[1]: ['000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg']
```

**UPDATE**:

You can also extend / improve this to the following with using [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
In [2]: np.array([np.array(b'000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg', dtype='|S40').tolist()]).flatten()
Out[2]:
array(['000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg'],
      dtype='|S40')
```

This also works with loadtxt:

```
In [3]: np.array([np.loadtxt('split_file_name', dtype=bytes).tolist()]).flatten()
Out[3]:
array(['000914_0017_01_0017_P00_01.tifresize.jpg',
       '000925_0017_01_0006_P00_01.tifresize.jpg',
       '000919_0017_01_0012_P00_01.tifresize.jpg'],
      dtype='|S40')
```

Comment: Hi Nico Albers,thank you very much, your method works! I would further know how np.array works here? It seems that it converts list containing of multiple characters back again to a array, right?

Comment: yes, exactly. I use this to have the possibility to use the [flatten method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) to not have nested lists there.